# Jasper Report JRElement Set Y value

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to set the value for X and Y at run time as follows

```
JasperDesign design = null;
design = JRXmlLoader.load("YourReport.jrxml");
JRElement jasperelement = null;

jasperelement = design.getPageHeader().getElementByKey('somekeyname');

if (jasperelement != null) 
{
    jasperelement.setX('someintegervalue');
    jasperelement.setY('Someintegervalue'); //This Method does not exits ?????????
}
```

Here SetY method not available for JRElement . What is the other way to set Y value. Actually in the design it is textfield.

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake. Need cast as follows

```
JasperDesign design = null;
design = JRXmlLoader.load("YourReport.jrxml");
JRDesignTextField jasperelement = null;

jasperelement = (JRDesignTextField) design.getPageHeader().getElementByKey('somekeyname');

if (jasperelement != null) 
{
    jasperelement.setX('someintegervalue');
    jasperelement.setY('Someintegervalue');  
}
```